# splashscreen doesn't show main activity in android

Tags: android, splash-screen

I followed the below link to show splash screen (which is a pop -up box) in my app.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidSplash.aspx

When I launch the app it shows splash screen (pop -up box) which is a desired behaviour. But I want the main activity to be displayed behind when there is a splashscreen(pop-box). 
Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: I used the same code that is there in the URL. The only change  I made to it is I added android:theme to the splashscreen activity in the mainfest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform both splash screen, and your activity task in a same activity ie, your main activity.

after `setContentView(R.layout.main);` start the splash screen thread.